# Grid Group By Error

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I tried group telerik grid using drop down list

grouping method source code is bellow

```
 try
        {

            this.grd.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();//clear all group expressions
            grd.MasterTableView.GroupsDefaultExpanded = false;

            GridGroupByExpression expression = new GridGroupByExpression();
            GridGroupByField gridGroupByField = new GridGroupByField();
            gridGroupByField = new GridGroupByField();
            if (cboGroupByItem1.SelectedValue != "0")
            {
                gridGroupByField.FieldName = cboGroupByItem1.SelectedValue;
                gridGroupByField.HeaderText = cboGroupByItem1.SelectedItem.Text;
                expression.SelectFields.Add(gridGroupByField);
            }

            if (cboGroupByItem2.SelectedValue != "0")
            {
                gridGroupByField.FieldName = cboGroupByItem2.SelectedValue;
                gridGroupByField.HeaderText = cboGroupByItem2.SelectedItem.Text;
                expression.SelectFields.Add(gridGroupByField);
            }

            grd.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Add(expression);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            grd.Rebind();
        }
```

when grid rebind method it will generate bellow error

> An error occurred adding a relation to DataRelationCollection. Please,
>   make sure you have configured the expressions properly - both
>   GroupByFields and SelectFields are required!

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line after you add the gridGroupField to expression.

```
expression.GroupByFields.Add(gridGroupByField);
```

As the error message says, you need to add the fields you want to groupby.
If you have an aggregate field you dont have to add it to the expression as GroupByField, only as SelectFields.

Hope it helps.